# Consultas asíncronas a base de datos

Tags: c#, sql-server, programacion-asincrona

Buenas tengo un lío gordo con la programación asíncrona.
Cuando hago consultas a la API de una tienda online, siempre uso el operador `await`.
Cuando implemento estas en un método, siempre retorno el resultado con `Task<T>`.
Sin embargo, cuando intento realizar lo mismo con consultas a una base de datos, recibo el error:

> Error CS1061  "int" no contiene una definición para "GetAwaiter" ni un
> método de extensión accesible "GetAwaiter" que acepte un primer
> argumento del tipo "int" (¿falta alguna directiva using o una
> referencia de ensamblado?)
> Un ejemplo de lo que intento hacer:

```
public async Task<Int32> ObteNumFills()
{
    Int32 nRegs = 0;
    string connectionString = Cconnexio.RetornaCadenaConnexio(BddParams);
    string query= "Select COUNT(codigo) FROM empleados where edad > 24;
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        cn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
        try
        {
            nRegs = await(Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            nRegs = 0;
        }
    }
    return nRegs;
}
```

Esta consulta es muy simple y no debería demorar más de unos milisegundos, pero como podría realizar esta tarea de forma asíncrona?

Comment: tip.. usa dapper.. ahora.. porque pones await(int32)? no alcanza solo con el await?

Comment: Sé que tengo que pasarme a un ORM...
Aún declarando nRegs como int a secas tampoco me funciona el await.

Comment: usa https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbcommand.executescalarasync?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que utilizar los métodos asíncronos `cn.OpenAsync()` y `cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync()`

```
public async Task<Int32> ObteNumFills()
{
    Int32 nRegs = 0;
    string connectionString = Cconnexio.RetornaCadenaConnexio(BddParams);
    string query= "Select COUNT(codigo) FROM empleados where edad > 24";
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        //       |
        //       V
        await cn.OpenAsync();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
        try
        {
            //                         |
            //                         V   
            nRegs = (Int32)(await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            nRegs = 0;
        }
    }
    return nRegs;
}
```